# Restore the original array after merge Sort based on it's steps

Tags: algorithm, recursion, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

i'm trying to write an algorithm to reconstruct the original array from the sorted one. considering input value is a string of 1s and 2s which 1 means in merging part of merge sort, element from left subarray is chosen and 2 means element from right subarray is chosen.
how can i do it? specially i have problem on that part that merge sort appends what ever is left from a subarray to final list.
for example: it's given 12212 as input string on an array of numbers [1,2,3,4]. it means that there is a permutation of numbers 1 to 4 that if you give it to merge sort, it will give you 12212. that permutation is 2 4 3 1 .

Comment: Why would the part that appends the tail of one of the sublists be a problem?  Unless that part did not produce entries in the merge trace, in which case I don't think the problem is tractable.

Comment: Otherwise, I'm inclined to think that the biggest trick would be determining the boundaries of the subarrays, but that is doable.

Comment: it didn't.  1s and 2s are only produced in main while of merge function. so those elements that are added to after finishing of main while don't make any 1 or 2

Comment: Then I think you're hosed.  Maybe you should go back and check the requirements, or if it's under your control, fix the sort.  The problem is that you cannot reliably split the overall merge trace into the traces of all the individual merges.  Or I don't think you can, anyway, unless possibly you have other constraints in play that you have not presented?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/164664/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

When you're recording the steps for a merge, you'll either get enough 1s to consume the whole left array OR enough 2s to consume the whole right array.  For a 2+2 merge, these are the possibilities:

```
11
121
122
211
212
22
```

This set of strings is always *prefix-free*, meaning that if you know where the sequence for a merge starts, then you can tell where it ends.

Unfortunately, it's not *suffix-free*.  It includes both `22` and `122`, for example.  That means that you can't tell where it starts by knowing where it ends.  If your string ends in `...1122`, for example, and you know that it ends in a 2+2 merge, it could be either a `22` merge or a `122` merge.  There's no way to tell the difference without tracing all the merges from the start.

That makes it a little tricky to write your un-merge-sort function, because you have to start at the beginning of the step record string.

In fact, the easiest way to do this un-merge is:

1. Make a sorted array of the numbers from 0 to n-1
2. Mergesort the array, but use your index string instead of comparisons
3. Now you have an array that maps each position to the original index of the element that ended up there.  Use this to undo your sort in O(n) time.

Comment: i think second line of algorithm is wrong. it gives me a wrong answer

Comment: can you elaborate about second part. what does it do?

Comment: Yes, this should work.  My comments on the question recognized that you cannot just run the sort backwards, but I overlooked that you could replay it *forward* to discover the final position corresponding to each initial position.